# Чем отличается Comparable от Comparator?

Tags: java

Когда использовать Comparable, а когда Comparator?

Comment: По идее тем же, чем отличается "сравниваемый" от "сравнивателя"

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В чем разница между Comparable и Comparator?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639143/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-comparable-%d0%b8-comparator)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Классы реализуют `Comparable`, чтоб можно было потом сортировать за счёт реализации `compareTo(Object)` метода.

Если класс реализует этот интерфейс, то можно использовать потом  `Collection.sort()` или `Arrays.sort()`. Объекты будут сортироваться основываясь на реализации `compareTo(Object)` метода.

Например:

```
public class Country implements Comparable<Country>{  

       @Override  
       public int compareTo(Country country) {  
        return (this.countryId < country.countryId ) ? -1: (this.countryId > country.countryId ) ? 1:0 ;  
       }
}
```

При вызове `Collection.sort()` на коллекции объектов этого класса, они будут сравниваться основываясь на `compareTo(Country country)`.

А `Comparator` используется, чтоб реализовать сортировку по кастомному полю, типо:

```
List<Country> listOfCountries = new ArrayList<Country>();
[...]
Collections.sort(listOfCountries,new Comparator<Country>() {  

      @Override  
     public int compare(Country o1, Country o2) {  

         return o1.getCountryName().compareTo(o2.getCountryName());  
     }  
});
```

Будут отсортированы объекты основываясь на сравнении имён стран.

Если резюмировать, то:

**`Comparable`** - реализуется внутри класса. По сути, определяет обычный/естественный порядок сравнения объектов.

**`Comparator`** - реализуется вне класса. Можно реализовать различные варианты сортировки, основанные на сравнении различных полей.

Answer (score 0):

Comparable - имплементится самим классом, когда нужен натуральный порядок сортировки. Пример - класс String.

Comparator - имплементится другими классами. Дает возможность отделить реализацию сравнения от класса и сделать несколько реализаций сравнения по разным параметрам для одного класса.

```
                     | Comparable             | Comparator
Package              | java.lang              | java.util
Functional Interface | Yes                    | Yes
Method               | int o1.compareTo(o2)   | int comparator.compare(o1, o2)
-1 if                | o1 < o2                | Same
1 if                 | o1 > o2                | Same
0 if                 | o1 == o2               | Same
Implement            | Class itself           | Separate classes
Defines              | Natural ordering       | Sorting by different parameters
Examples             | String, Date, Wrappers | For third-party classes
```