# В чем разница между Comparable и Comparator?

Tags: java

Получается, это дублирующие друг друга вещи. Может, есть какие-то реальные различия?

Comment: Простыми словами - Comparable - сравниваемое, Comparator - сравнитель (то, что делает сравнение)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. `Comparator` и `Comparable` - это оба интерфейсы
2. Коллекция (ну хорошо, объект) является `Comparable`, когда объект может быть как то сравнен с другим объектом.
3. `Comparator`, в отличие от этого — это способ сравнения объектов.

**Пример:** школьники на уроке физкультуры, физрук говорит: *строиться по росту!* - ученики быстренько сравнивают свои росты и строятся - кто выше вперед, кто ниже в хвост строя - это пример реализации `Comparable`, где в качестве `compareTo(сосед)` используется рост учеников.

**Второй пример:** те же школьники. Директор дает задание учителю математики сравнить учеников по успеваемости. Математичка берет журнал и сравнивает учеников по успеваемости - здесь работает `compare(ученик1, ученик2)` - `Comparator'ом` выступает математичка. Аналогично компаратором может выступить русичка или трудовик.

Comment: Коллекция не является Comparable

Comment: Пример с физруком некорректен: критерий сравнения по росту не является присущим ученикам изначально.

Comment: Капитан очевидность на марше :)

Comment: @Barmaley этот вопрос отредактирован правильно после комментариев Майорова Павла или нет?

Comment: Смысл не изменился, а замечания персонажа не считаю существенными - *он так видит*

Answer (score 11):

С философской точки зрения Comparator является субъектом - индивидом познающим внешний мир, сравнивая объекты.

А Comparable является объектом, т.е. на него направлена познавательная деятельность субъекта. И одновременно он сам является субъектом, который пытается познать другой объект, сравнивая его с самим собой.

Comment: Хороший ответ, мне нравится) Но если человек на практике мало понимает в чем разница, с таким объяснением думаю ему будет еще сложнее

Answer (score 7):

Принципиальное различие в том, что в Comparable "зашит" один-единственный алгоритм сравнения объектов, в то время как Comparator представляет собой внешнюю заменяемую настройку.

Архитектурно, Comparable - это интерфейс *значения*, в то время как Comparator - настройка *контейнера*.

Следует использовать Comparable в том случае, когда задается естественный (наиболее логичный) порядок. Например, для строк это регистрозависимое лексикографическое сравнение, а для длинных чисел - сравнение по значению.

Во всех остальных случаях - без отдельного компаратора не обойтись.

Answer (score 3):

Comparable - имплементится самим классом, когда нужен натуральный порядок сортировки. Пример - класс String.

Comparator - имплементится другими классами. Дает возможность отделить реализацию сравнения от класса и сделать несколько реализаций сравнения по разным параметрам для одного класса.

|  | Comparable | Comparator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Package | java.lang | java.util |
| Functional Interface | Yes | Yes |
| Method | int o1.compareTo(o2) | int comparator.compare(o1, o2) |
| -1 if | o1 < o2 | Same |
| 1 if | o1 > o2 | Same |
| 0 if | o1 == o2 | Same |
| Implement | Class itself | Separate classes |
| Defines | Natural ordering | Sorting by different parameters |
| Examples | String, Date, Wrappers | For third-party classes |

Comment: На всякий случай: справка по форматированию таблиц: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables

Comment: @insolor, мне нравятся таблицы в текстовом виде: | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | . Их нельзя так оставлять? Много раз на английском стеке видел таблицы именно в таком текстовом виде.

Comment: Раньше не было возможности вставить таблицы, поэтому извращались. Но конечно можете вернуть как вам нравится.